# Переход из консоли в графический интерфейс

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Здравствуйте.

Делала клиент-серверное приложение в консоли, теперь надо переделать его с графический интерфейсом. Я создала проект Приложение Windows Form. Только пока не понимаю, где писать основной код выполнения программы. Вот например - для запуска сервера - на форму кнопку притащила - на нее обработчик - отвечающий за инициализацию Winsock, открытие сокета, связывание с локальным адресом, ожидание подключений. А потом по консольному проекту идет извлечение из очереди сообщений

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Я попыталась в Load формы сервера написать инициализацию библиотеки Winsock, создание сокета, связывание его с локальным адресом, нормально работает, дальше по консольному проекту - нужно цикл обработки извлечения сообщений из очереди.

```
SOCKET accepted_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;
while(true) {
    if ((accepted_socket = accept(server_listen_socket, NULL, NULL)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        Form1->richTextBox1->Text += "\nОшибка при извлечении сообщения из очереди...\n";
        closesocket(server_listen_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        break;
    }
    else {
        Form1->richTextBox1->Text += "\nСоздан отдельный поток для нового клиента...\n";
    }
}
```

В `Load`  формы пробовала - сервер не запускается даже... Куда этот код писать - никак не пойму..

Answer (score 1):

В нормальном виде это должно выглядеть как

1. основной поток - обработчик вашей формы.
2. доп поток - обработчик очереди сообщений(входящ)
3. доп поток - обработчик очереди сообщений(исходящ)

Пункт 2 и 3 повторяются n раз для распараллеливания на многоядерных процессорных системах. Создается дополнительный поток, который будет отслеживать "забитость" очереди и перекидывать клиентов из переполненных очередей в более свободные, но вам пока рано трогать это, создайте приложение в 2-х потоках пункт 2 и 3 объедините в этом потоке.

Comment: ..так в каком-же файле писать функцию извлечения сообщения из очереди? и функцию обработки каждого клиента..